# Sending audio over SIP client

Tags: java, audio, text-to-speech, sip, audio-processing

I have 2 clients, the Java SIP client `net.sourceforge.peers` and a Zoiper on the other side.

I am trying to send prepared audio files on the Java client using `net.sourceforge.peers.demo`

On the `net.sourceforge.peers`, I will be reading the incoming audio, transcribing it, then using nlp I will generate a text, tts it (nlp and tts are done outside `net.sourceforge.peers`), store it as a file (`C:\\Users\\absin\\Downloads\\output1.wav`) and then stream it back to the Zoiper client.

I have configured `MediaMode.captureAndPlayback` in `net.sourceforge.peers.peers-demo` because I want to capture the incoming audio, process it and send a prepared audio.

I have the following class to do so:

```
public class StreamSoundManager extends AbstractSoundManager {


@Override
    public byte[] readData() {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\absin\\Downloads\\output1.wav");
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        byte[] byteArray = null;
        try {
            // create FileInputStream object
            fin = new FileInputStream(file);

            // create string from byte array
            byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(fin);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File not found" + e);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Exception while reading file " + ioe);
        } finally {
            // close the streams using close method
            try {
                if (fin != null) {
                    fin.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.err.println("Error while closing stream: " + ioe);
            }
        }
        return byteArray;
    }
```

I am getting the audio on my Zoiper client, however the audio is slow and broken.

If I change the `MediaMode.file` in `CustomConfig.java` and modify the `handleAck` in `MediaManager` class like below, I get proper audio on my Zoiper client

```
case file:
            if (fileReader != null) {
                fileReader.close();
            }
            // String fileName = userAgent.getConfig().getMediaFile();
            String fileName = "C:\\Users\\absin\\Downloads\\output1.wav";
            fileReader = new FileReader(fileName, logger);
            startRtpSession(destAddress, destPort, codec, fileReader);
            try {
                incomingRtpReader = new IncomingRtpReader(rtpSession, null, codec, logger);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("input/output error", e);
                return;
            }
            incomingRtpReader.start();
            break;
```

What am I missing in my `StreamSoundManager` class on Java client?

My use case is that of capturing incoming audio stream from Zoiper, processing it  in the Java client and then preparing audio using tts and nlp and sending it to the Zoiper client. Can I achieve this using `MediaMode.file` in the `CustomConfig` for the `peers` demo? I have gone through the `peers-demo`, however I can't find this particular use case.